# Run-Time error '1004': The field "Active" Does Not Exist

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm receiving this error on a user's PC. They are using Project 2013 on Windows 7. On our own test machines with Project 2013 on Windows 10 and Project 2016 on Windows 10), we are not seeing the same error.

The error's getting thrown all over the place, but one example is `FilterEdit` found here here:

```
Sub STAT_Leads_Preds()
    FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Predecessors", Test:="contains", Value:="-", ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Actual Finish", Test:="equals", Value:="NA", Operation:="And", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    If Not pActive Then
        FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Active", Test:="equals", Value:="Yes", Operation:="And", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

It's unclear why this message appears. ["Active" is, in fact, a field.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/active-task-field-81769c1e-6b4b-4014-bad4-21471fdaa99e) And, like I said, we are not seeing this issue on test machines.

For reference, here's what the error looks like:
[image]

Comment: Can you compile code on Win7? If not most likely a reference is broken, because you referenced to a newer libary ( e.g. to`Mircosoft XML v6`, but Win7 provides only`Mircosoft XML v4 ` and you can't use a newer ref with an older lib, only the other way around). Use late binding or develop on the oldest supported system.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - I looked into late binding. My dev machine is Windows 7. Using Project Professional 2016 everything compiles. One lead I've uncovered is that Project Standard 2010+ doesn't have the "Active" field...Seems promising. I'll report back once we test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Project Standard does not have the "Active" field. Our solution involved checking for the edition of the software using Application.Edition, which can be [one of two values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjeditiontype): `pjEditionProfessional` or `pjEditionStandard`.

Here's how the code ended up looking:

```
Sub STAT_Leads_Preds()
    FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Predecessors", Test:="contains", Value:="-", ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Actual Finish", Test:="equals", Value:="NA", Operation:="And", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    If Not pActive And Application.Edition = pjEditionProfessional Then
        FilterEdit Name:="STAT_Leads_Preds", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Active", Test:="equals", Value:="Yes", Operation:="And", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```